# Does there exist a $G$-invariant polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]^G$ such that $f(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = 0$ and $f(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\text{GL}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ and let $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be two points which do not belong to the same $G$-orbit in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

**Question.** Does there exist a $G$-invariant polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]^G$ such that $f(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = 0$ and $f(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 1$?

Comment: Probably you assume that $u$ and $v$ are not on the same $G$-orbit? Then yes, just take any polynomial $p$ such that $p(Gu)=\{0\}$, $p(Gv)=\{1\}$ and define $f(x):=\sum_{g\in G} p(g\cdot x)$.

Comment: @PeterFranek: Minor nit-picking. We have to normalize your definition of $f$ by dividing by the order of $G$.